# :-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-x64-1_71.lib'

Tags: c++, qt

I use Qt 4.10.0 in windows 7.
When I tried to compile my project, error occurs:
:-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc141-mt-x64-1_71.lib'

```
-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-12-23T11:43:59
#
#-------------------------------------------------
QT       += core gui
QT       += serialport
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = MDT
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp \
checkboxheader.cpp \
ft_file_info.cpp \
ui_dll_function.cpp \
ui_utility.cpp \
startprocess.cpp \
qmdttimer.cpp \
usbswitch.cpp
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
checkboxheader.h \
ft_file_info.h \
ui_dll_function.h \
ui_utility.h \
startprocess.h \
qmdttimer.h \
QMtrace.h \
usbswitch.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
INCLUDEPATH += ./DownloadLib
LIBS += -LD:\EPS_projects\2018to2019\29_IOT_MDI\IoT_MDT_official\lib - 
 lDownloadLib \
 QMTRACE.lib \ 
 EfuseLibrary.lib \  -      
LD:\EPS_projects\2018to2019\29_IOT_MDI\IoT_MDT_official\boost_1_71_0\libs \
RESOURCES += \
icons.qrc
#LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -lQMTRACE   / -lEfuseLibrary
#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/.
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/.
LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -lEfuseLibrary
#win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -lEfuseLibrary
#win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -lusb_relay_device
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/DownloadLib
```

I use boost boost_1_71_0  in my project.

Comment: Your project is specifying that it's expecting 64-bit boost libraries compiled with multi-threading using VS 2017, so do you have this? If not then you need to specify different params so it links to the version you have

Comment: I use Qt Creator 4.10.0， I do not use VS2017

Comment: It has to be using some kind of C++ compiler, it is detecting or defaulting to VS2017 somewhere in your setup, you need to investigate this